# PHP sessions wont allow acces to my "CART"

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, redirect, authentication

I want the user to only be able to access the cart if they are logged in.

index.html

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

Cart.php

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION["userName"]))
{
    header("Location: ../index.html");
}

?>
```

connectivitity.php

```
function SignIn() 
{ 
    session_start(); //starting the session for user profile page 
    if(!empty($_POST['user'])) //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text 
    { 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass'])) 
        { 
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass']; 
            header("location: ../PHP/Cart.php");

        } else { 
            echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERD WRONG ID AND PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY..."; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    { 
        SignIn(); 
    }
```

at this point no matter the variations i try, it keeps redirecting me back to index.html. Even thought i changed the header to take me straight to Cart.php file.

Im running a godaddy hosting package on CPanel, this is in the .htaccess file

```
Options +MultiViews
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: _deprecated_ mysql functions with Invalid query string syntax near `userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'`

Comment: not sure exactly what that means, im still an infant when it comes to php

Comment: It means every function you use that begins with `mysql_` will cease to function and exist in a near future, so recommendations are to change them to `mysqli_` (it's not just add an `i` in the end of `mysql`, read the manuals for further information), or a `PDO` object.

Comment: `Cart.php` needs a `session_start();` before `if(!isset($_SESSION["userName"]))`.

Comment: thanks @sean That perfectly fixed the problem of redirecting me! however once i fixed that every time i try to visit my domain it trys to download the files? so i clearned my .htaccess file and it works now? any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this the *core* problem but you should however look for it.

**1)** Instead of a query with improper string concatenation:

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Make it more simple:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$user' AND pass = '$pass'";
 $query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

**2)** No matter if you use/set/unset/ or do whatsoever with `sessions`. Always write `session_start();` in the beginning of your code.

Your fixed `cart.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["userName"]))
{
    header("Location: ../index.html");
}

?>
```

> Note: Even though these fixes should help you solve your problem. But it is
>   highly recommended to move to `mysqli` or `PDO` with prepared statements
>   as this code is still prone to SQL Injection.